# how the -incdir statement is supposed to be used in library mapping definitions?

Tags: verilog

The standard provides syntax for use of the '-incdir' in library maps:

```
library_declaration ::=
library library_identifier file_path_spec { , file_path_spec }
[ -incdir file_path_spec { , file_path_spec } ] ;
```

However, nowhere in the standard its behavior is defined, at least I could not find it.

There is a specific clause for the relative file names:

> . specifies the directory containing the lib.map

> Paths that do not begin with / are relative to the directory in which the current lib.map file
> is located.

So, there is just no place for the -incdir statement.

Does anyone has an explanation of its  behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an [open issue](https://accellera.mantishub.io/view.php?id=1166) in the IEEE 1800 standard inherited from the IEEE 1364 standard. You will need to look at the documentation of the tool you are using. But in general, it means any file from that directory will get included into that library.

Comment: according to the vendor, '-incdir' in the 'library' statement overrides command-line include search path for mapped files.